# Why cannot find MvvmCross-Binaries\XS-iOS-Mac\bin[Debug|Release]?

Tags: mvvmcross

I cannot find MvvmCross-Binaries\XS-iOS-Mac\bin[Debug|Release] binaries though I can see the recommendation about using it on Mac from https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Tutorials.
Can I not use MvvmCross binaries on Mac anymore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That image is out of date - it dates back to the old dark days before PCLs really worked on iOS.

You can now use nuget or the VisualStudio-built assemblies. (However, right now we are also in the dark transition stage between Classic and Unified Xamarin.iOS APIs)

Comment: 1. can I use VS-built assemblies in XS on Mac? 2. I cannot find "Cirrus" prefix from nuget mvvmcross packages. are they same as previous cirrus assemblies?